# How to identify loads for a Payload Adapter System during Rocket Launch?

Tags: launch, engineering, payload, ariane, analysis

Good afternoon,

A classmate and me are doing a project for university in which I have to perform several structural analysis of the Payload Adaptar System 937C from Ariane V (picture shown).

[image: PAS 937C]

The disposition of the PAS 937C is seen also in the figure below, more precisely in the upper stage:

[image: Ariane V]

We have performed a simplified [CATIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CATIA) model, but now we need to identify the main loads in order to perform shear, traction, compression and buckling, bending and torsion studies during a typical launch.

We would appreciate if anyone gave us any insight on how to quantify these loads, as we have no idea right now on where to start.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The loads (acceleration, vibration) that occur during launch are specified in the [Ariane 5 user manual](http://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Ariane5_Users-Manual_October2016.pdf). 
The payload is attached to the top of the PAF via the ring at the top.